# google HomeGraphService reportStateAndNotification

Tags: java, kotlin, google-home, google-smart-home

I try to implement [StateReporting](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/integration/report-state) with the [HomeGraphService](https://developers.home.google.com/reference/home-graph/rpc) api for my google action.
For this I followed the google [state-report](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/integration/report-state) documentation.

The issue is that the reportStateAndNotification function seems to do nothing.
It just returns an empty list of com.google.api.services.homegraph.v1.HomeGraphService$Devices$ReportStateAndNotification.
Also the state does not change in the HomeGraphViewer.

When I use the access token from credentials.accessToken with curl everything works fine.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
val stream = Base64.getDecoder().decode(homeGraphServiceKey)
    val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream.inputStream())
        .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph")
    credentials.refreshIfExpired()
    val token = credentials.accessToken


    val service = HomeGraphService.Builder(
        GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
        GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
        HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)

    )
        .setApplicationName("ff")
        .build()

    val states = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, Any>>()
    val state = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    state["on"] = true
    states["hue:cE1"] = state


    val request =
        ReportStateAndNotificationRequest().setRequestId(
            kotlin.random.Random.nextLong().toString()
        )
            .setAgentUserId("7b1d52e3-e68f-46cd-a8b9-6ce1fdfe5b62").setPayload(
                StateAndNotificationPayload().setDevices(
                    ReportStateAndNotificationDevice().setStates(
                        states.toMap()
                    )
                )
            )


    val response = service?.devices()?.reportStateAndNotification(request)
```

curl:

```
{
  "requestId": "123ABC",
  "agentUserId": "7b1d52e3-e68f-46cd-a8b9-6ce1fdfe5b62",
  "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "states": {
        "hue:cE1": {
          "on": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer token”   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d @request   "https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:reportStateAndNotification"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. When you implement Report State you send us the data every time the state of the device changes. If you are seeing any discrepancies with the state of device you are sending to us and one in the [Homegraph viewer](https://smarthome-test-suite.withgoogle.com/devices) tool, you can open a [public issue tracker ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) and we can take a look.
We highly suggest taking one of our [Smart Home Codelabs](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer?hl=en#5) to get a hands-on experience on how to implement Report State, RequestSync etc.